# Use of "please call again" in a high street shop

Tags: word-usage

The 1963 Broadway musical "She loves me" is set in a Budapest parfumerie in 1934.

In the play, every time a customer leaves the shop, the employees sing a short jingle:

> Thank you madam, please call again. Do call again, madam.

I was wondering why the verb "call" is used, considering that the business serves casual customers that don't book appointments.

Does "call" have a special meaning in this historical, geographical or gergal context?

Comment: See [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/call) sense 6.

Comment: You don't see it as much of late, but 20-30 years ago it would not be unusual to see, in the US, a sign hanging near the exit that said "Thank you -- Please call again".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common, but older, usage of the word "call" is to "pay a visit."  Usage is typically in a phrase like "Shall we call on Fred?" which would me "Shall we pay Fred a visit?"

In the case of "Do call again, madam." the shop is simply expressing their wish that madam returns to visit the shop again.